# Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag - can SO simplify the requirement?

Tags: feature-request

I am asking for clarification of the warning:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag

I have `9` different wiki tag edits (Research Assistant `9/50)`, yet the system prevents me from suggesting the new tag for a particular tag.

Does it mean that I have to edit and my edits have to be accepted 5 times for the root tag 5 times to be able to suggest a synonym for that particular tag?

That would be quite disruptive procedure!

Can this system be simplified? For example after editing at least `50` tags with positive score `>= 50` user can suggest synonyms?

Comment: Having a score of 5 in a particular tag has nothing to do with editing in that tag. It means you have to ask questions or answer question in that tag with a score of 5.

Comment: @DBL Thank you! Now it makes sens. Can someone just add this clarification to the SO warning: `You have to ask questions or answer question in that tag with a score of 5 to be able to suggest synonyms` ?

Comment: What else should it mean? There is no voting on tags itself? Also the top-lists of the tags and tag badges are built by votes from questions/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no voting on tags itself.

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag

Having a score in a tag means that you have to ask or answer in that tag and get up-votes. This is the same score used in tag-badges and tag top-user lists.